# How to POSITION my Marker to Always Follow the Slider-Handle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I'm currently learning CSS and JS layouting. How do I make my MARKER always follow the SLIDER-HANDLE (cursor) wherever it goes like they were grouped as one?

```css
    .slider {
        -webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
        appearance: none;
        width: 100%; /* Full-width */
        height: 25px; /* Specified height */
        background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
        outline: none; /* Remove outline */
        opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
        -webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
        transition: opacity .2s;
    }
    
    .sliderticks p {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      width: 1px;
      background: #D3D3D3;
      height: 10px;
      line-height: 40px;
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }
```

```html
    <form>
        <div class='slidecontainer' >
            <div  class='sliderticks'>          
     
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class='add-queston-btn'>
                <img src='Images\pointmarker.png' data-quiz-number='2' z-index='2'>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Where is your JS? Could you please post out the full exemple of what you've tried? That'll help us try and find a solution :)

Comment: The code you have shown so far does not even come close to reproducing what your image shows. We therefor don‘t know how you implemented any of the functionality, how the slider is moved, etc. - and therefor we also can’t answer your question. So please start with a _proper_ [mcve] of what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youc can set a position to image using Jquery

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLaw30mr/)

```js
//set a begining position to img
var slider = $(".slider")[0];
var sliderPos = slider.value / slider.max;
var pixelPostion = slider.clientWidth * sliderPos;
$(".img").css("left",pixelPostion-7 + "px");

//set a position to img when slide move
$(document).on('input', '.slider', function() {
var slider = $(".slider")[0];
var sliderPos = slider.value / slider.max;
var pixelPostion = slider.clientWidth * sliderPos;
$(".img").css("left",pixelPostion-5 + "px");
});
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
}

.img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAPBs.png");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">  
   <input type="range"  min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider"/>
   <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```